# The entity name must immediately follow the " in the entity reference

Tags: xml, entity, xpages

Every time I open one of my xpages I get following popup/dialog (see image). I have looked in the source pane trying to find an error but can't find it and the problem is not listed in the source pane or in the problems eclipse view.

the xpage is compiling and working fine, but the popup is annoying.

what is the best approach for finding what is casusing this?

The entity name must immediately follow the " in the entity reference

[image: Error]

Comment: If you're not on R8.5.3+, can you upgrade?

Comment: Of course :-) Could you try same database on a different PC+Designer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This must be a bug in the custom visualization used in the custom control.  I tried it with

```
if( true && true ){
    return "home"
}
```

and got the same error.  But only when 'Computed on Page Load'.  When I changed it to 'Compute Dynamically' it worked fine.  I guess something isn't liking the ampersands &&.

BTW, it also didn't like ||.

Edited 2012-08-30:  Even when I put in ...

```
return "home"
```

and set it to "Computed on Page Load" it generates an error and will not render the custom control correctly in the design view.

I believe that showing the id of the default content or, in this case the code that computes the id, in the custom visualization is what's causing the problem.  Someone needs to handle the $ generated when computing on page load and any && and || that are in the code if they really feel the need to show it there.

Answer (score 1):

The error normally means you have broken XML. For example a & instead of &amp; in a field.

Try removing elements from the page and see if it compiles or not. Once you have narrowed it down post the code.

This can also happen if your page has code set to read XML from a web source but you get back a webpage instead of valid XML.

Answer (score 0):

I have tracked this error down to be caused by the dynamic content control in extlib.
using the following code you can reproduct the error  (note: you need to have extlib installed). the same ssjs code put in a computedText works.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xe:dynamicContent id="dynC" useHash="true">
    <xe:this.defaultFacet><![CDATA[#{javascript:if(n.contains("news") && u.contains(userid)){
return "yes"
}
 }]]></xe:this.defaultFacet>
</xe:dynamicContent>
</xp:view>
```

any thoghts on this?

Comment: Your sample is incomplete. What is "n" and "u" supposed to be?

Comment: sorry, here they are, they both return a vector i believe. var n = getGroupDetails(id,"Sections","");
var u = getGroupDetails(id,"MembersID","");